# Displaying Checked values in Radio button reactJs

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, react-props

I have a Api call which get a object with question Id and response Id given by the user. When I revisit the questions, I want to see the previously given answers checked in the radio button.

I can get the relevent responce id but how to make the radio button checked?

```
import React from "react";
import "./radioopions.css";
const RadioOptions = (props) => {
  const result = props.response;
  console.log("result 1:", result);

  const QID = props?.questionId;
  console.log("result 2:", QID);

  const getCheckedAnswer = () =>{
    {
      result?.map((res) => {
        if (QID === res?.questionId) {
          const answer = res?.response;
          console.log("res",res?.response)
          return answer;
          
        }
      });
    }
   
  }

  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="radio-container">
        <div className="radio-options">
          {props.options?.map((ans, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={ans.optionID}>
                <div className="answer-options">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="ans-op-overlay-resolve"
                    value={3}
                    checked={
                      props.selectedAnswer === i || getCheckedAnswer()
                      //|| props.previousAnswer === res?.response
                    }
                    onChange={() => props.handleAnswerOPtion(i)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`option-${i}`}>{ans.option}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default RadioOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically check the radio button which corresponds to the response of the user for the current question, I suggest you do use the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./radioopions.css";
const RadioOptions = (props) => {
  const result = props.response;
  console.log("result 1:", result);

  const QID = props?.questionId;
  console.log("result 2:", QID);

  const getCheckedAnswer = () =>{
     return result?.find((res) => {
        return (QID === res?.questionId) 
      }); 
  }

  // This function will return the response id for the current question        id

  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="radio-container">
        <div className="radio-options">
          {props.options?.map((ans, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={ans.optionID}>
                <div className="answer-options">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="ans-op-overlay-resolve"
                    value={3}
                    checked={
                      getCheckedAnswer()?.responseId === ans.optionId
                    }
                    onChange={() => props.handleAnswerOPtion(i)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`option-${i}`}>{ans.option}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default RadioOptio
```

Feel free to make some changes to the above code, but the main idea is that you want to find the specific object inside of your response which belongs to the current question and it will give you the **responseId** that you require.

After being able to retrieve that value, you can set the **checked** property to true in your radio buttons, only for the relevant option which matches the response that the user has provided for the current question.

Answer (score 0):

Change response value in **apiResponse** variable inside **useEffect** to set initial value for radio to be either 1, 2, or 3 => this is controlled component for radio button

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "favorite color?",
    options: [
      { optionID: 1, option: "Red" },
      { optionID: 2, option: "Green" },
      { optionID: 3, option: "Blue" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "favorite food?",
    options: [
      { optionID: 1, option: "Pizza" },
      { optionID: 2, option: "Burger" },
      { optionID: 3, option: "Salad" }
    ]
  }
];

const RadioOptions = (props) => {
  const { response, questionId, options, handleAnswerOption } = props;

  const getCheckedAnswer = (optionID) => {
    const responseObj = response.find((res) => res.questionId === questionId);
    return responseObj ? responseObj.response === optionID : false;
  };

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const answerId = parseInt(e.target.value);
    handleAnswerOption(questionId, answerId);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="radio-container">
        <div className="radio-options">
          {options?.map((ans, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={ans.optionID}>
                <div className="answer-options">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id={`option-${i}`}
                    name={`question-${questionId}`}
                    value={ans.optionID}
                    checked={getCheckedAnswer(ans.optionID)}
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                  />
                  <label>{ans.option}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate API response data
    const apiResponse = [
      { questionId: 1, response: 1 },
      { questionId: 2, response: 2 }
    ];
    setResponse(apiResponse);
  }, []);

  const handleAnswerOption = (questionId, answerId) => {
    const newResponse = [...response];
    const responseIndex = newResponse.findIndex(
      (res) => res.questionId === questionId
    );
    if (responseIndex !== -1) {
      newResponse[responseIndex].response = answerId;
    } else {
      newResponse.push({ questionId, response: answerId });
    }
    setResponse(newResponse);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {questions.map((q, i) => (
        <div key={q.id}>
          <p>{q.text}</p>
          <RadioOptions
            response={response}
            questionId={q.id}
            options={q.options}
            handleAnswerOption={handleAnswerOption}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```